# Is there a list of flags for Node.js?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-harmony

I'm trying to find a list of all flags that Node.js accepts, specially those for ES6-Harmony features, but I can't find any. Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Run `node --v8-options`.  That displays the various flags you can set to change the behavior of V8

E.g. The flags for the harmony features show up in there:

```
 --harmony_typeof (enable harmony semantics for typeof)
     type: bool  default: false
 --harmony_proxies (enable harmony proxies)
     type: bool  default: false
 --harmony_weakmaps (enable harmony weak maps)
     type: bool  default: false
 --harmony_block_scoping (enable harmony block scoping)
     type: bool  default: false
```

Answer (score 11):

If you apply the `--help` switch to node from the shell, you'll get a list of available flags;

```
node --help
```